# Meaning of Facebook's proxied email addresses

Tags: facebook, email, alias

How can email addresses of the form `xxx@proxymail.facebook.com` be used?

Is it possible to send normal mails to those addresses that are forwarded somewhere or are there deeper restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These used (?) to be handled for Facebook applications as a proxy so users do not have to release their email address publicly. Facebook assigns one when granting access to an application and the user requests an anonymous email instead. A temporary one is randomly generated for the user to receive emails from the application developer.